# Check if the system: $\sin \left(\frac{2\pi n x}{b-a} \right), \cos \left(\frac{2\pi n x}{b-a} \right)$is orthogonal over the interval [a=12, b=14].

Tags: trigonometry, orthogonality

> Check if the system: $\sin \left(\frac{2\pi n x}{b-a} \right), \cos \left(\frac{2\pi n x}{b-a} \right)$is orthogonal over the interval [a=12, b=14].

My work thus far:
$$\begin{align}
\int^{14}_{12} \sin\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{14}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{14}\right)dx &= \int^{14}_{12} \frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{7}\right)dx \\[4pt]
&= \frac{7}{4n}\pi \left[-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{7}\right) \right]^{14}_{12} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{7}{4n}\pi \left[-\cos\left(4\pi n\right) +\cos\left(\frac{12\pi n}{7}\right) \right]
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{7}{4n}\pi \left[\sin \left(\frac{40\pi n}{7} \right) \sin \left(\frac{-16\pi n}{7} \right)\right]^{14}_{12}  = $$
I don't know how to proceed to show that it is not equal to zero. Is it as simple as just writing $4\pi n \neq \frac{12 \pi n}{7}$ or is there some catch?

Comment: In your first integral, shouldn't the denominator be $2$ instead of $14$?

Comment: Use the same sum-to-product identity that helped with [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3690146/409).

Comment: @Blue Ok, but I still don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: $b-a = 2$ not $14$.